# Why am I getting an index out of range error?

Tags: python, csv

```
def improve_fight_song(title):
    Tech_file = open("RamblinWreck.txt","r")
    myfile= open("ImprovedFightSong.txt","w")
    lines = Tech_file.readlines()

#Lets find all of the engineer cases.
    for s in range(len(lines)):
        if "engineer" in lines[s]:
           z = lines[s].replace("engineer","programmer")
           myfile.write(z)



    myfile.close()

improve_fight_song("kjhk")
```

I cannot seem to figure out why I am running out of range here. I have tried funning the for loop through the length of lines which is just a list of all the lines as strings, but that does not work either. Below is the actual error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/treawethington/Documents/HW6.py", line 16, in 
    improve_fight_song("kjhk")
  File "/Users/treawethington/Documents/HW6.py", line 8, in improve_fight_song
    if "engineer" in lines[s]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are there only 10 lines in Tech_file?

Comment: Similarly, why did you choose `range(11)` do control your loop?

Comment: No, there are 12. However I have tried 11, 12, 13, for the range and I still get the same error.

Comment: Because whatever value of `s` you are trying to use to access the `lines` list, is out of bounds. Remember lists start at index 0. If your list is size 11, then `lines[10]` is actually the upper limit of your list. `lines[11]` will surely give you an index out of range.

Comment: I should have changed that in the code. sorry

Comment: Why not `for s in range(len(lines))`?

Comment: You should output what is happening in each iteration of your loop to see what is happening and surely you will figure it out. Furthermore, you don't need to loop over your lines like that. You can just do `for line in lines` and each `line` will be the line in your list, so you can simply check equality for each line you get in your iteration.

Comment: I just edited the code to what I originally had which was for s in range(len(lines)), this still gives an out of range index though

Comment: Could you post the full exception traceback? It shouldn't be possible for this code to throw an IndexError.

Comment: idjaw thank you for the response. I have attempted to output each iteration of the for loop it seems as though the loop is not running. I can get nothing that is inside of the loop to write to a file.

Comment: Insert a print in loop, look what happened

Comment: C.Quian, Thank you for the response. I have done this and am seeing no results. Did you find something else happened?

Comment: I have figured it out. Somehow the RamblinWreck.txt was blank and so the the range of 0 in the loop would return out of range.

Comment: Ah. I suspect you accidentally opened that file in write mode at some stage, thereby clobbering its previous contents.

Comment: Might this have been caused by the fact that the file has not been closed?

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code ran fine when I tested it, but I think what you are looking for is this:

```
def improve_fight_song():
    tech_file = open("RamblinWreck.txt", "r")
    myfile = open("ImprovedFightSong.txt", "w")
    lines = tech_file.readlines()

    # Lets find all of the engineer cases.
    for line in lines:  # no need for range here
        if "an engineer" in line:
            myfile.write(line.replace("an engineer", "a programmer"))
        else:
            myfile.write(line)

    myfile.close()
    tech_file.close()  # close this file as well


improve_fight_song()
```

Where [this](http://textuploader.com/d1yef) is the content of `RamblinWreck.txt` and [this](http://textuploader.com/d1ye3) is the content of `ImprovedFightSong.txt` after you run `HW6.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally not loop over a list of lines by index. Just use:

```
for s in lines:
    if 'engineer' in s:
         z = s.replace('engineer', 'programmer')
```

Note that your original code *only* writes the lines that have changed.

Instead of iterating over all lines, you could just do the replace for the whole contents of the file:

```
with open("RamblinWreck.txt","r") as infile:
    text = infile.read()

outtext = text.replace('engineer', 'programmer')

with open("ImprovedFightSong.txt","w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(outtext)
```

Comment: Is it for avoiding memory issues that you did not use a nested `with` statement on open?

`with open('a.txt', 'r') as a, open('b.txt', 'w') as b:
    b.write(a.read().replace('engineer', 'programmer'))`

Comment: @MaxChrétien Simple is better than complex. ;-)